# Indexación de iconos con material design

Tags: html, vue.js, material-design, seo

Se esta indexando el elemento `assignment_ind` y `perm_identity`, que son nombres de iconos en Material Design. ¿Cómo debería ser la estructura correcta para que no suceda esto? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo:**

```
     <v-menu offset-y class="menu-navbar-settings" v-show="auth != false">
        <v-btn
          icon
          color="deep-orange darken-1"
          dark slot="activator"
          class=""
        >
          <v-icon class="pharol-icon">settings</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(item, index) in userOptions"
            :key="index"
            :to="item.path"
          >
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
              <v-icon :color="item.iconColor">{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-avatar>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile
            @click="logout()"
          >
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
              <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">power_settings_new</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-avatar>
            <v-list-tile-title>Cerrar sesión</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
```

**Arreglo:**

```
userOptions: [
        { path: '/auth/profile', title: 'Perfil', icon: 'perm_identity', iconColor: 'grey lighten-1', },
        { path: '/auth/update', title: 'Modificar contraseña', icon: 'vpn_key', iconColor: 'grey lighten-1', },
      ],
```

Comment: Si colocas el código será mucho más probable que alguien te pueda ayudar

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Has probado a ponerle un aria-hidden al icono? No sé si con eso se solucionaría el problema de Google, pero podría ser una opción (si no lo añade vue por defecto).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba reemplazando el nombre por el código correspondiente.

```
<!-- assignment_ind -->
<i class="material-icons">&#xe85e;</i>

<!-- perm_identity -->
<i class="material-icons">&#xe8a6;</i>
```

Guía de códigos:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints

Comment: Muchas gracias, dejame intentarlo.